# Notepad++ variable name syntax highlight

Tags: notepad++, javascript, syntax-highlighting

How to add syntax highlight color to local function scope variable, and also block scope variable when using the let keyword, so I can clearly see local from global variables.

JavaScript language specifically, if it's a per language configuration.

Answer (score 0):

[Does this not work for you?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqaDY.png)
(To get to this window, double click the bottom left corner, it might says 'Normal Text File'. Then, just select JavaScript from the prompt.)

Local scope variables highlight just fine for me.

Comment: No dear sir/ma'am, I'm not asking how to syntax highlight my JavaScript, I'm asking how to syntax highlight my local and block scope variables. So I can clearly see local from global.